# HubSpot-Trello Integration: Issues with the Trigger

Tags: zapier, hubspot

I'm facing difficulties while trying to connect HubSpot with Trello, specifically with the trigger action. My goal is to automatically create a Trello card when the owner of a ticket changes to a specific one. However, I haven't been successful in getting this integration to work.

I tried simplifying the trigger to only execute when the ticket property changes. Additionally, I've validated in Zapier that it's the specific owner I'm looking for, but I still can't progress beyond the property changes.

Any suggestions or advice on how to address this issue? I would appreciate any help!

1. Configuration Tips: Suggestions on how to adjust specific settings in HubSpot or Trello to ensure the ticket property change is detected correctly.
2. Data Validation: Tips on verifying data consistency between HubSpot and Trello, ensuring that owner information is being transmitted correctly.
3. Review Zapier Configuration: Recommendations to review the settings in Zapier, ensuring that filters and conditions are correctly set to trigger the action in Trello.
4. Alternatives or Different Approaches: Ideas on alternative approaches to achieve the same result, perhaps using different actions or conditions in Zapier.
5. Common Errors: Identification of possible common errors that might be preventing the integration from working and suggestions for troubleshooting.